# Relative vs Absolute in CSS

Tags: html, css

Can any one explain me in detail about relative and absolute in CSS. All the descriptions tells me that absolute can be placed any place I want (that means I can use top, bottom, etc). I can achieve the same with the relative as-well. I was just checking a small example in relative and absolute in W3schools, wherein relative occupies the whole line but absolute doesn't. I am confused with this.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_relative

Can anyone explain me with a perfect example about their difference?

Comment: The accepted answer in the dupe is wrong in the absolute positioning explanation. Take a look at the comment with 72 upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the better understanding to Css Positioning from this source

> **Quick Summary of the 4 Kinds of Positioning:**
>
> **Static** - Static positioning is the default, it is what happens when
>   you set no positioning. The element (the tag and its content) stays in
>   normal page flow.
>
> **Relative** - The element's box is still part of the page flow, and but
>   its location is changed vertically and/or horizontally relative to its
>   own normal position in page flow.
>
> Being part of flow (being in page flow) means that an element will
>   push later elements in flow further down, and be pushed further down
>   by elements in flow that are before the current element.
>
> Example of Relative CSS positioning:
>
> ```
> .fromorig {position: relative;
>      top: 200px;}
> ```
>
> **Fixed** - The element's box is removed from the normal page flow, and you can set exact vertical and horizontal
>   position of the element relative to the browser window. Additionally,
>   the fixed element's contents will NOT scroll away like normal HTML
>   page contents do, they will stay in their current position in the
>   browser window. Fixed positioning was not supported by IE until
>   version 7.
>
> Example of Fixed CSS positioning:
>
> ```
> .nevermove {position: fixed;
>       top: 200px;
>       left: 200px;}
> ```
>
> **Absolute** - The element's box is removed from the normal page flow, and you can set exact vertical and horizontal
>   position of the absolute element relative to the element it is inside.
>   Additionally, the absolute element's contents will scroll vertically
>   (and/or horizontally) like normal HTML page contents do.
>
> Example of Absolute CSS positioning:
>
> ```
>  .moveit {position: absolute;
>    top: 200px;
>    left: 200px;}
> ```

see demo at:

[CSS Positioning With example](http://www.yorku.ca/nmw/facs1939f13/week02/css_relVSabsVSfixed.html)